# MySQL Easy more than function

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to do this:

```
SELECT Filmai.Pagrind_atlik, ( COUNT(Filmai.Pagrind_atlik)) AS Kiek_kartu_filmavosi 
FROM Filmai 
WHERE  Kiek_kartu_filmavosi >2 
GROUP BY Filmai.Pagrind_atlik;
```

But it wont allow me to make >2 thing. So maybe any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT Filmai.Pagrind_atlik, 
( COUNT(Filmai.Pagrind_atlik)) AS Kiek_kartu_filmavosi
FROM Filmai  
GROUP BY Filmai.Pagrind_atlik
HAVING Kiek_kartu_filmavosi >2;
```

`WHERE` is applied before `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` is applied after (and can filter on aggregates).

Comment: You have to use HAVING after the GROUP BY, otherwise you get a syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

WHEN you want to limit an aggregate function's results you can't use it in the WHERE clause. You have to use HAVING:

```
SELECT Filmai.Pagrind_atlik,
  COUNT(Filmai.Pagrind_atlik) AS Kiek_kartu_filmavosi
FROM Filmai
GROUP BY COUNT(Filmai.Pagrind_atlik)
HAVING COUNT(Filmai.Pagrind_atlik) > 2
```